# Call function of template class created at runtime

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, late-binding

I have a tricky question about C++(11) template classes and their instantiation with types determined at runtime:

Following scenario:
The user defines the type of a template class using a config file (ROS parameters). This determines only the type of the template class, not the further logic:

Class definition:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
    //[...]
}
```

Exemplary code:

```
/* [Read parameter and write result to bool use_int] */

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> myclassptr {nullptr};
if(use_int) {
    myclassptr.reset(MyClass<int>);
} else {
    myclassptr.reset(MyClass<double>);
}

myclassptr->foobar();

/* [more code making use of myclassptr] */
```

So this code is (of course) not compiling, because the unique_ptr template must be specified also with the template type. However, then the problem arises that the template type must be the same for all objects assigned using `reset`.

One ugly solution would be to copy the code `myclassptr->foobar();` and the following into each branch of if/else, which I really don't like.

I would like to see a solution similar to this:

```
/* [Read parameter and write result to bool use_int] */

MyClass<use_int ? int : double> myclass;
myclass.foobar();
```

What I have read so far is that something like this is also not possible.

Does anybody have a nice solution for this?

Comment: Perhaps a common base class: `template <typename T> class MyClass : public IClass;`

Comment: This is what interfaces are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
class IClass{
  virtual ~IClass {}
  virtual void foobar()=0;
};
template<typename T>
class MyClass:public IClass {
public:
  void foobar() override {
    // code here
  }
};
std::unique_ptr<IClass> myclassptr {};
if(use_int) {
  myclassptr.reset(new MyClass<int>());
} else {
  myclassptr.reset(new MyClass<double>());
}
myclassptr->foobar();
```

`boost::variant` would be another solution, but is usually used for unrelated types.  Type erasure could be done, but again that is usually done when you have unrelated types you want to impose a uniform interface on.

In other languages generics look sort of like `template`s, but are actually an abstract interface with auto-generated typecasting and some typechecking added.  C++ `template`s are function or class compile time factories.  Two outputs of such factories are unrelated at runtime by default, and you can add such relations if you want.

Comment: That looks like a nice and clean solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want, you can make MyClass a variant type that holds either an int or a double, or you could use type erasure to hide the implementation behind an interface. The [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html) library can help to implement the former.

Comment: Thanks for the idea using Boost.Variant. It might be working, be I had problems using classes without a default constructor. In addition, when I have understood the theory correctly, I need a visitor class for each function I want to call. I don't like that overhead or additional code.